# How to Break or Split DOI numbers in two lines in a References List

Tags: reference, citations, journal, doi, scopus

I am writing a research paper where I need to use `DOI` numbers of the references. But for some references, it is showing unnecessary white spaces (see the 1st attached file) since the `DOI` can not be fitted in the line. To solve this problem I used `shift+enter` to break the `DOI number` into two separate lines. It kind of solves the problem (see the 2nd attached file) but when I convert the `word` file into `PDF`, and click on the `DOI` number it leads to an error page instead of the referred journal page.

How to solve this issue? Is there any good way to Split the `DOI` numbers in two lines without getting error?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Not very elegant, but you could use [shortDOI.org](https://shortdoi.org/) on those that create too ugly whitespace.

If you use a reference manager, replace the original URL/DOI there with your shortened version.